# Why the plus signs before the quotation marks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I've stumbled across something I can't quite get my head around. Let's say there's a product object:

```
let product = {
  img: "../image.jpg"
}
```

Now if I want to access product.img in a url, I can do something like the following:

```
const getProductImage = product => ({
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + product.img +')'
});
```

My question is: what is going on with this bit?:

```
' + product.img + '
```

EDIT: Okay, this question starts from the wrong premise, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code simply adds the strings together, so the result is the new string concatenated:

```
'url(' + product.img +')'.
```

For instance, if the `product.img` contains an url to an image, like: `'http:example.com/image1.png'` then the `backgroundimage` will end up containing:

```
'url(http:example.com/image1.png)';
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two sets of quotation marks:

```
'url('
```

and

```
')'
```

Not

```
' + product.img + '
```

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how you concat a string from variables into a single string.
It could be rewritten as follows:

```
let first = 'url('
let last = ')'
let final_string = first + product.img + last
```

Or in template literals (which is better where possible)

```
`url(${product.img})`
```